# page is not scrolling to specific div with id in reactjs using react bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

page is not scrolling to specific div with id but its working on desktop but not in mobile devices and tablet

I tried to use react-router hash link but still its not working don't know why?
need help??

```
function NavigationBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" variant="light" bg="light">
      <Container fluid className="m-2">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">
          <Logo />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md`} />
        <Navbar.Offcanvas
          id={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md}`}
          aria-labelledby={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md`}
          placement="end"
        >
          <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
            <Offcanvas.Title
              id={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md`}
            ></Offcanvas.Title>
          </Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Body>
            <Nav className="justify-content-end align-items-center flex-grow-1 text-center">
              <Nav.Link href="/#about">
                <span>01.</span>About
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/#work">
                <span>02.</span>Work
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link className="nav-last" href="/#contact">
                <span>03.</span>Contact
              </Nav.Link>
              <div style={{ width: "100px" }}>
                <Button Padding="0.65rem 1rem">Resume</Button>
              </div>
            </Nav>
          </Offcanvas.Body>
        </Navbar.Offcanvas>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Comment: hello @Rohan , are you sure `id={\`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md}\`}` this is correct because I guess you added an extra " }"  ?

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez I think thats no the problem even I change it, its not working can we give me other solutions bro?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fix it by adding a delay after closing offcanvas before navigating to div here is my full navbar component also i made offcanvas close after click on any link

i used 'md' breakpoint here for expand because i want nav to expand on tablets if you want it collapsed on tablet use 'lg' breakpoint instead

```js
import React from 'react'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';
import { useState } from 'react';
const Navigation = () => {
  const [showOffcanvas, setShowOffcanvas] = useState(false);

  const handleLinkClick = () => {
    setShowOffcanvas(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const target = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
      if (target) {
        const element = document.getElementById(target);
        if (element) {
          element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
      }
    }, 500);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar fixed='top'  expand={'md'} >
    <Container fluid>
      <Navbar.Brand>logo</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-${'md'}`} 
             onClick={() => setShowOffcanvas(true)}
            />
            <Navbar.Offcanvas
              id={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-${'md'}`}
              aria-labelledby={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-${'md'}`}
              placement="end"
              show={showOffcanvas} 
              onHide={()=>setShowOffcanvas(false)}
            >
                 <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              </Offcanvas.Header>
              <Offcanvas.Body>
                <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <Nav.Link href='#hero' onClick={handleLinkClick} >Me</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href='#skills' onClick={handleLinkClick}>Skills</Nav.Link>
               <Nav.Link href='#projects'onClick={handleLinkClick}>Projects</Nav.Link>
               <Nav.Link href='#contact'onClick={handleLinkClick}>Contact</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </Offcanvas.Body>
            </Navbar.Offcanvas>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
  
  </>
  )
}

export default Navigation
```